# why x>>1 is not always same as x/2?

Tags: bit, operation

why `x>>1` is not always same as `x/2`?

Especially when it is negative odd number, for example:

```
    x = -3;
    Assert.assertNotEquals(x / 2, x >> 1);
    x =  3;
    Assert.assertEquals(x / 2, x >> 1);
```

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how `>>` works. `>>` is not "divide by 2", it just ends up with the same answer for certain situations. For example, on 8-bit values:

`3` is `0b00000011`; right-shift by one bit is `0b00000001`, which is `1`.

`-3` is `0b11111101`; right-shift by one bit is `0b11111110`, or `-2`.

However, integral division `/` in Java is defined to always round down towards zero - so `(-3) / 2` becomes `-1` (as it is closer to `0` than `-2` is).

EDIT: The comments refer to my brainfart in switching `>>` and `>>>` around.

Comment: I tested this in c and -3 >> 1 = -2. According to http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/op.html, ">>
returns expr1 shifted right expr2 bit positions; if the type of expr1 is signed, 1 bits are shifted into the high order bits, otherwise 0 bits are shifted in. Mathematically equivalent to expr1 / 2expr2." They appear to be wrong about them being mathematically equivalent, but the shifting in of 0 or 1 depending on sign appears correct.

Comment: @TonyRuth: Your source is mistaken. There is no set definition of [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_\(mathematics\)#Of_integers) if the dividend is not cleanly divisible by the divisor; since the operator `/` and operator `>>` *are* both defined, they are clearly not *mathematically* equivalent. Furthermore, you are talking about C; I explicitly address language incompatibilities in my last paragraph.

Comment: when I test in java `-3 >> 1 = -2`.

Comment: @TonyRuth: Derp, I switched them around. Will edit to remove the irrelevant stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan  and TonyRuth for your help. with your feedback I find a [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift) hope it useful for readers